# Which building is it?

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

> Deep in the heart of London ,
>
> The great symbol of Britain lies,
>
> A hundred meters in the sky,
>
> The great bell chimes.

Which building is it?

Comment: I think it should be "great bell", not "grand bell".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a trivia question, not a puzzle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is:

> Big ben

The great symbol of Britain lies

> One who thinks to London surely thinks of Big Ben as its symbol

A hundred meters in the sky

> It is 315 feet (96.0 m) high

The great bell chimes.

> [The Great Bell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Ben#Great_Bell), of course.

Comment: if this is correct, this trivia is too simple. just with "london" and "building" i have it .. :/

Comment: @lois6b I can just agree with you

Comment: i searched "trivia" into meta to see whats is the current opinion .. i think its valid as puzzle as long as is not globaly known..

Comment: !Spoiler remark! The actual name is Elizabeth Tower (previously the Clock Tower). The Big Ben is the name of the bell.

Comment: @lois6b No.  Plain trivia questions are not puzzles and do not belong on Puzzling.SE.